# Problem with refresh token every hour in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito to handle oauth autentication, and after login cognito returns a token to refresh every hour.
I did some logic to refresh this token every hour using setTimeout, but if the user refresh the page this will not work anymore.
Someone know a alternative for this?

I tried to use setTimeout and interval from rxjs to refresh the token every one hour, but results in the same problem after page refresh.

```
private async setAutoRefreshToken() {
    return interval(3500000).pipe(startWith(1), switchMap(() => this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(map(auth => {
      const data = auth.AuthenticationResult;
      return data;
    }))));
  }
```

Comment: The standard pattern to refresh a token is to keep track of the datetime the token was acquired. Each time the app needs to the token, check the datetime and verify the token is not about to expire in a minute or so- otherwise request a new token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution might be to store the token, together with the timestamp you requested it at, in the localstorage. Every time you access the token, you can check if it is still valid and otherwise request a new one (or you might want to request a new one if the token is about to expire in the next minutes).

In order to manage the case you are not accessing the token for about an hour, you can still add a timer that checks every 10 seconds if the token is about to expire by checking against the timestamp.

This also works after reload.